# Почему доступная функция не вызывается через неявное преобразование?

Tags: c++, дизайн-языка, function-overloading

Почему следующая программа выдаёт ошибку, а не вызывает доступную функцию с int-ом через неявное преобразование к `42`?

```
struct A {
    void foo(int);    
private:
    void foo(double);
} a;

int main() {
    a.foo(42.);
}
```

Comment: Потому что имеется перегрузка `foo(double)`, не требующая никаких преобразований. @maestro https://godbolt.org/z/PqsT8s31f

Comment: @user7860670 Она не доступна, т.к. в секции `private`

Comment: Проверка доступа производится *после* выбора подходящей перегрузки.

Comment: @user7860670 есть идеи, почему так сделано? Ведь это и нагрузку увеличивает на компилятор из-за лишних перегрузок, которые всё равно не могут быть вызваны, и даёт ошибки в таких случаях.

Comment: Потому что в вашем варианте ошибочно может быть сделан вызов, который преднамеренно заблокирован от вызова с помощью модификатора доступа. Так устраивает?\

Comment: Представьте, что было сделано по-вашему и модификатор доступа влиял бы на перечень доступных перегрузок. Тогда бы вызов `foo(42.)` в месте с одним доступом вызывал бы одну функцию, а в месте с другим доступом - другую. Также это бы приводило к тому, что при изменении уровня доступа у кода (допустим сделали функцию `friend`) в ней бы неявно менялись вызовы. В С++ хватает мозговыворотных заковырок и без этого.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, звучит разумно.